# Capturing word after a particular string is present in a file and add a line if it's present

Tags: python, regex

I read a file having the following text

```
    this is::b(test file).
    extra this is::another(test file).
    this is::a(test file)
```

I am able to read the file and write it in another file.I want to capture  the word after

> this is:: and before '(' i.e 'b' from the first line and 'a' from the 3rd line and store it in a list  and nothing from the 2nd line since it has extra word before 'this is'
>   I tried using the Regular expression:

```
   for item in lines:
     print(item)
     fw.write(item)
    found=None

found=(re.search('this is::(.+?)[)]',y).group(1)
```

where y= string read from the file

```
y=''.join(lines)
```

But it is capturing only 'b' and adding the new line after each line.

Can someone please suggest how should I go about achieving it.
Expected File:

```
 this is::b(test file).
 An extra line:b
 extra this is:another(test file).
 this is::a(test file).
 An extra line:a
```

Comment: Please add an example of your expected results.

Comment: My Expected File Should Looks like this : this is::b(test file). "Extra line"
    extra this is::another(test file).
    this is::a(test file) ."Extra line"

Comment: Use the regex: [`^[ ]*this\s*is::([^(\n]+)(?=\()`](https://regex101.com/r/J2XPqK/1) and fetch the value of Group1

Comment: @Saurabh; I've updated my answer to reflect your desired results -- I'm not sure why you were choosing to join the lines, nor does your actual result make sense given the code you provided, so I can't tell you specifically what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is along the lines of what you are after?

[Edit: Updated code to reflect change to the question]

```
import re

lines = ("this is::b(test file).",
         "extra this is::another(test file)",
         "this is::a(test file)",
         "this is::another test")

words = []
for line in lines:
    words.append(line)
    found = re.search('^this is::.*[(]', line)
    if found is None: continue
    word = line.split('::')[1].split('(')[0]
    words.append(f"An extra line:{word}")

for word in words:  
    print(word)  # You can save to file here instead of print
```

Yields

```
this is::b(test file).
An extra line:b
extra this is::another(test file)
this is::a(test file)
An extra line:a
```

Note, I gave a regex for the simplest case; If you need a better regex -- you owe it to yourself to work that out independently. Here is a great tool, [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/), for helping test regex expressions.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

### For capturing text

For your example, you can search for the string literal `this is::` then create a sub pattern `(.*?)` (the ? makes it non-greedy).

#### Example

```
import re 

s =  """
this is::b(test file).
extra this is::another(test file).
this is::a(test file)
"""

res = re.findall("this is::(.*?)\((.*?)\)", s)
for r in res:
    print(r)
```

#### Output

```
('b', 'test file')
('another', 'test file')
('a', 'test file')
```

### For appending line to a file

I'm not clear on what you want here, but if you simply want to append to a file... see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file)

#### Example

```
with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("Found something!")
```